# .html causes 404 error

Tags: php, html, nginx, joomla2.5

I am running a joomla 2.5 site on ubuntu server with php/nginx/mysql (fairly new to nginx)

My problem is that when a user hits a url, I need it to ignore the .html file extension.

For example, if you hit mysite.com/page then it renders the page fine.

If you hit mysite.com/page.html then it will throw a 404 error. Which is because there isn't actually a 'page.html' page on my site. Its a K2 article alias. Yes, I could not put .html in but its not me adding content to the site, its the client. I have recently moved server and before it worked fine, now it doesnt so I know I have missed something in the config.

I know I can get nginx to do the opposite of what I want, with `try files`. Not sure how to get it to do the reverse.

This is my nginx config:

```
location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to index.html
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
    # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
}
```

Now I know if i had a page.html page and I wanted to hide the .html I could add `$uri.html`

What I want to know is how to get nginx to try `page.html` if it cant find it try `page`

Comment: does this format work? `http://example.com/index.php/page_uri.html` ? , replace `page_uri` with the actual page link

Comment: No adding `index.php` into the URL doesnt work, I should have mentioned I tried that already.

Comment: sharing the `.htaccess` inside the joomla root directory would help

Comment: Important information needed: What generates the page.html links?  Do they come from search engines of does joomla generate them?

Comment: I believe it is google, but I am not sure. As the client has also typed in .html on some of their aliases. In regards to htaccess I am not using one. Thing is they worked fine on the old server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So turned out to be a Joomla Config variable. Under SEO settings in global config set 'apply suffix' to yes. I feel quite stupid. Thanks to all those that tried to help, as always much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a potential solution I managed to come across:

```
location / {
    # If /{foo} is not an existing file or directory, rewrite to /{foo}.html
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^(.+)$ /$1.html break;
    }
    # Redirect all {foo}.html URLS to /{foo}
    rewrite ^/(.*)\.html$ /$1 redirect;
}
```

If you can correctly write `.htaccess` rewrite lines, try using a [htaccess-to-nginx converter](http://winginx.com/htaccess)

As commented, this will check for the existence of a directory, file, etc. using the current URL. If nothing exists, it will attempt to request the url with `.html` appended.

Additionally, if `.html` is already present in the URL, it will redirect to the URL without `.html`

Comment: That doesn't appear to work, though it is doing something. It gives the nginx 404 page rather than the joomla 404 page.

Answer (score 0):

Quick workaround:

```
rewrite ^(. *)\.html$ $1 break;
```

Should be the first rewrite in the stack, even before try_files.